# Get extra posted from browser in android using url scheme

Tags: android, bundle, url-scheme

I'm using below code for invoking android application from web broswer -

```
<a href="intent://com.xyz.android"> Open Application </a>
```

I've set following code in my manifest -

```
 <activity
    android:name="com.xyz.android.Activity"
    android:label="xyz">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>    
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <data android:scheme="intent" android:host="com.xyz.android" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

When I've clicking on the link "Open Application", it's opening my application as expected.
Now Question is that can we get extra posted from link in my application.
For example - I want to pass emp_id and name's value from webview and want to fetch that value in android application. How could it be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I tried and worked below for me -
Html code -

```
<a href="intent://com.xyz.android?emp_id=111&name=abc"> Open Application </a>
```

Android code as below -

```
if(getIntent() !=null && getIntent().getData() !=null){
    String param1 = getIntent().getData().getQueryParameter("emp_id");
    String param2 = getIntent().getData().getQueryParameter("name");
}
```